# Flexible XSL Date / DateTime Transformation

Tags: xslt, tibco, businessworks, businessevents

We're using Tibco BusinessWorks to pass an XML document to a Tibco BusinessEvents process. Because BusinessEvents does not have a DATE format, only DATETIME, we must change Dates in the source XML document before sending to BusinessEvents, and map the response's DateTime values back to simple Dates.

**This is both annoying and cumbersome.**

In an attempt to improve BusinessWorks' performance, I'm writing a stylesheet to handle the mapping. Here's what I've got.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:inf="http:/the.company.namespace">

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inf:PriorExpirationDate | inf:OrderDate | inf:SegmentEffectiveDate |
                    inf:SegmentExpirationDate | inf:CancelDate | inf:NewBusinessEffectiveDate |
                    inf:NewBusinessExpirationDate | inf:RenewalEffectiveDate | inf:RenewalExpirationDate |
                    inf:QuestionDate | inf:ViolationDate | inf:ConvictionDate |
                    inf:EffectiveDate | inf:RatingDate | inf:AdvanceDate |
                    inf:SIDRevisionDate | inf:DriverLicensedDate |
                    inf:ESignatureDate | inf:UploadDate | inf:CancelDate |
                    inf:CancelProcessedDate | inf:CancelEffectiveDate | inf:CreatedDate |
                    inf:QuoteCreationDate | inf:QuoteModifiedDate | inf:QuoteExpirationDate |
                    inf:RateStartDate | inf:RateEndDate | inf:ChangeEffectiveDate | inf:PostDate |
                    inf:EffectiveDate | inf:ExpirationDate | inf:BirthDate |
                    inf:InstallmentDueDate | inf:CommercialDriverLicenseDate ">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="concat(format-date(text(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]'), 'T00:00:00')" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

While functional, this not ideal. I'd prefer NOT to have to enumerate each element I need transformed, I'd rather specify a TYPE that needs to be converted.

**(1)** Does XSL offer this functionality ?

**(2)** Alternatively, there are some element names that may be DATEs in one location and DATETIMEs in others. Is there an efficient way of excluding some DATETIME elements if I know the parent by name ?

**(3)** Lastly, does anyone see room for enhancement beyond the scope of the question ?

*Some context: The original mapping is done inside BusinessWorks' editor, where the GUI generates its own mapping file, a several-hundred-line series of if/then/else statements. For a 50k document (our average) this amounts to nearly 20ms overhead per transformation for a web service that completes its actual work in fewer than 50ms. This is the bottleneck that must be improved upon.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[. castable as xs:date]">
 <!-- Your code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So incredibly simple, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @JHarnach, You are welcome. And yes, XSLT is both powerful and elegant. Watch XSLT 3.0 for new features few could imagine.